# How do I reload an object back to its original state?

Tags: unity

I have a game where a wall is destroyed. I would like to click a button to reload the wall back to its initial state. I have only managed to reload the scene, using `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel))`, but it takes to long.

How do I reload an object back to its original state?

Comment: check https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html,

Comment: Can you show us what you're currently doing to destroy the wall? There are a few different ways to do that, some easier to reverse than others. ;)

Comment: I use it : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7193

Comment: My wall is made up of single bricks, which are cut into pieces when i hit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an object in your hierarchy called "wall" with all of your bricks as children of this gameobject. I also think you are not going to move this gameobject at runtime since it is a wall. You could solve this problem by taking the "wall" gameobject as a parameter in a script. Now you could access all the children via that script, create a Vector3[] called something like "positions" and another array for the gameobjects. Now you assign the gameobjects.tranform.position[i] = positions[i]; (the code is not tested). Basically you make a "backup" of all the cube positions, in order to reset them when you press the button. You can see a similar example here, it's made by Brackeys(https://youtu.be/eqlHpPzS22U)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it so: I was able to remove all the pieces of the wall. And I want to insert a new, ready wall on the scene. How can I put a ready-made object on the scene during the runtime?

Comment: Is this a solution, or a new question? If you want to clarify your question, please do so using the edit button. We can't answer an answer post, so it's best to keep all your questions in the question post at the top.

Comment: You should not answer/add details to the question by answering. Please consider editing the question